# Sorting dictionary does not return same type ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary, hashmap

Following is my dictionary

```
var dictionary: [String:[UserNotification]?]?
```

Following is code to add elements to dictionary

```
 do {
       notificationArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [UserNotification]
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
 dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: notificationArray ?? [UserNotification]() , by: { (element: UserNotification) -> String in
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: element.receiveDate ?? Date())
        return strDate
    })
```

Now I am using following code to **sort dictionary by date**

```
 let sortedDic =  dictionary?.sorted(by: {
        print( $0.key < $1.key)
        return $0.key > $1.key

    })
```

Above code works fine but it ***does not allow*** assignment sortedDic to dictionary

```
dictionary = sortedDic //Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: [UserNotification]?)]?' to type '[String : [UserNotification]?]?'
```

above line showing error says **"Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: [UserNotification]?)]?' to type '[String : [UserNotification]?]?'"**

how to fix this

Comment: No it has something to with JSON my question different

Comment: The answers explains why do you get this error, basicly.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered and can't be sorted, read the answer in the provided link again.

Comment: The solution is to hold an array/list alongside the dictionary.  You hold the dictionary keys in the array/list and sort it as required.

Comment: Also, having a optional as the value type of a dictionary is somewhat redundant.